# Rails + Devise HTTP header token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have in my devise config the following line to enable token authentication in HTTP header:

```
config.http_authenticatable = [:token]
```

However, whenever I try to access a resource, I receive a 401 when running the following:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token token=\"c9G52z6n6LpGt5Ls6omW\"" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/objects/
```

As proof that the token is correct, the following works:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/objects?auth_token=c9G52z6n6LpGt5Ls6omW
```

Has anyone managed to get token authentication in HTTP header working? I can't find much information on it apart from:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/o3Gqgl0yUZo

Comment: Alexander, have you solved this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I didn't manage to get HTTP token auth working with Devise as per the documentation.

Comment: Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6) about subj. Was helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

My implementation is based on this [post](http://blog.envylabs.com/post/75521798481/token-based-authentication-in-rails) and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6).

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_create :set_auth_token

  private

    def set_auth_token
      return if auth_token.present?

      begin
        self.auth_token = SecureRandom.hex
      end while self.class.exists?(auth_token: self.auth_token)
    end

end
```

**api_controller.rb**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate

  protected

    def authenticate
      authenticate_token || render_unauthorized
    end

    def authenticate_token
      authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
        user = User.find_by(auth_token: token)

        if user
          sign_in user, store: false
        end

        user
      end
    end

    def render_unauthorized
      self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Token realm="Application"'
      render json: 'Bad credentials', status: 401
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried to enable it that way with devise, but that didn't really worked for me :/

Meanwhile you can use this in your ApiController, if you don't want to use http auth, but still support token auth by http header:

```
before_filter :authenticate_with_http_token
def authenticate_with_http_token
  auth_header = request.headers['Authorization'].to_s
  token = auth_header[/token="(.*?)"/,1]
  return unless token

  user = User.find_for_token_authentication(auth_token: token)
  sign_in user if user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The authorization header's format is different.

Your `Authorization` header should look like this:

```
# HASHED_TOKEN = Base64.encode64("#{AUTH_TOKEN}:X")
Authorization: Basic #{HASHED_TOKEN}
```

Comment: But this is HTTP basic auth, I'm looking for HTTP token auth